# What will the code below output to the console and WHY?

Tags: javascript, operators

I am getting the output to below code but i don't know how its working ,Can anyone please tell me what
is the reason to the output.

```js
console.log(1 + "2" + "2");
console.log(1 + +"2" + "2");
console.log(1 + -"1" + "2");
console.log(+"1" + "1" + "2");
console.log("A" - "B" + "2");
console.log("A" - "B" + "2");
```

Comment: Which of these are you confused about? Are you asking about the [Unary plus opeartor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Comment: I don't know how the operators are working in this code.

Comment: What's your exact question about this code? By running it, you can check what it prints - and by deconstructing it line by line, operation by operation, you can even debug it

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(1 + "2" + "2"); // it is concat as string
console.log(1 + +"3" + "2"); // 2nd + makes 2 as string to integer. but second 2 is string. so it makes 42
console.log(1 + -"1" + "2");// 2nd - makes 1 as string to integer. but second 2 is string. so it makes 02
console.log(+"1" + "1" + "2");// 1st - makes 1 as string to integer. and same behaviour of the first logging
console.log("A" - "B" + "2"); // - cannot used for string values. nor this reason find A - B is NAN and adding 2 as string.
//console.log("A" - "B" + "2); // syntax eerror. second " in 2 missing
```

Answer (score 0):

1. console.log(1 + "2" + "2");

Now the output will be 122 because 1,2 and 2 are strings. Similarly the output for the other ones would be

2. 32
3. 02
4. 112
5. NaN2 (means A-B is not defined and then 2 is used as string)
6. The sixth one code is wrong because there is no " from right end